# footer width set to 100%, position absolute not extending to right edge of browser window in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, safari, width

good morning, o mighty Stack.

we're working on a site built in wordpress, using the genesis theme framework.

it is here, http://foodtrucksnashville.com

Everything is fine and dandy in Chrome, Opera, FF and IE (close enough) until you look at it in Mobile Safari on the iPhone and iPad

the #footer-wrapper ( at the bottom, with the clouds and blue strip background ) is width: 100% position: absolute; bottom: 0; but alas, it does not extend all the way to the right of the browser viewport.

i have read a bit on mobile safari choking on position: fixed, but have been unable to locate anything that would be of use to me here. Hence the new Stack_Query.

thanks again, stack.

have a good one.

p.s. i'd like to avoid having to use JavaScript to solve this, ( you know, get the viewport width with jQuery and automagically assign that value to the #footer-wrapper ) but if that's what Stack says, then SO BE IT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent hazardous comportment of the viewport, you can configure it. Use `<meta>`tags to achieve that.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` makes the viewport maximized on the device. I have a 100% width footer in a mobile site, with no problem with this code.

Read the [official Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051) on this topic for further info.